# Wallpapers don't look good even when using my monitor resolution

Tags: windows, desktop-customization

So, I've been having an issue lately with my computer that's making wallpapers look kind of "bad quality"

My monitor is 1920x1080, 16:9 and I'm using 1080p wallpapers, and they have a sort of grainyness to them, like little dots on the edges of objects in the wallpaper.

I wanna get this sorted so I can have some crisp wallpapers.

[image]

Comment: These are artifacts caused by using low quality JPEGs. Use a lossless format (such as PNG, BMP or similar) or increase the JPEG quality to at least 95.

Answer (score 1):

The [wallpaper you are showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szyfz.png) has [compression artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact).

If you are sure that the original wallpaper does not have JPEG artifacts, see this Super User question: [Stop Windows 8 from converting wallpapers to low quality JPGs](https://superuser.com/q/507097/83694)

If the original wallpaper is showing the same artifacts, you'd need to contact the wallpaper vendor or artist to ask for a higher quality image.